# Failed to connent to mail server PHP PEAR

Tags: php

Guy I am trying this since morning. For more than a month my PHP Pear mail was working fine, but suddenly it has stopped, I am not understanding the problem. What could be it?

```
    $mail=$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $mailmsg);
    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
    }
```

It is giving out this error.

```
    Failed to connect to mail.escener.com:25 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (code: -1, response: )]
```

The code above the above code is absolutely correct so I haven't posted the complete code. Please suggest.

Comment: this is bcoz you don't have access check username and password

Comment: They are 200% correct

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your mailserver settings changed; you are either "blacklisted" or they changed their "authentication" to POP before SMTP or something